# search and replace text and numbers in Textfile using .NET c#

Tags: .net, regex, search, replace, find

I want to find and replace millimeters to centimeters inside a bill of materials description. I have to find the word mm next to int number and then change the word mm to cm and multiply the number 0.1 times, Problem is that descriptions may vary for example:

- Half plate ¼ inch length **188mm** height **1065mm**, ss 316 
  Lace 3/4 cal 16 x **1120 mm** ss 304
- Air coushion rode 3/16 **38mm** width, **972mm** length ss316
- Vacuum plate **L.972mm** **W.288mm** ss304

I have the following regex to find the text, but it doesn't work as expected, sometimes in finds 0mm in 150mm:

```
string txt = textBox1.Text;
string re1 = ".*?"; // Non-greedy match on filler
string re2 = "\\d+";    // Uninteresting: int
string re3 = ".*?"; // Non-greedy match on filler
string re4 = "\\d+";    // Uninteresting: int
string re5 = ".*?"; // Non-greedy match on filler
string re6 = "\\d+";    // Uninteresting: int
string re7 = ".*?"; // Non-greedy match on filler
string re8 = "(\\d+)";  // Integer Number 1
string re9 = ".*?"; // Non-greedy match on filler
string re10 = "(mm)";   // Word 1

// ".*?\\d+.*?\\d+.*?\\d+.*?(\\d+).*?(mm)"

Regex r = new Regex(re1 + re2 + re3 + re4 + re5 + re6 + re7 + re8 + re9 + re10,
   RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
Match m = r.Match(txt);
if (m.Success)
{
    String int1 = m.Groups[1].ToString();
    String word1 = m.Groups[2].ToString();
    MessageBox.Show("(" + int1.ToString() + ")" 
        + "(" + word1.ToString() + ")" + "\n");
}
```

So.., do you have any ideas? maybe a more complex regex or a library for find and replace... Thank you!!

Comment: [Here is a possible solution](http://pastebin.com/raw/5kF597eY) it can be developed to multiply the value by 0.1

Comment: Can't you match those numbers with something like [`@"(\d+)\s*mm\b"`](https://regex101.com/r/zS1kJ1/1) and then use a match evaluator to change into cm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working program on [Ideone](https://ideone.com/oRTJgn):

```
string s = @"Half plate ¼ inch length 188mm height 1065mm, ss 316 Lace 3/4 cal 16 x 1120 mm ss 304
             Air coushion rode 3/16 38mm width, 972mm length ss316 
             Vacuum plate L.972mm W.288mm ss304";

Regex regex = new Regex(@"(\d+)(\s*)(mm)");

string ns = regex.Replace(s, delegate (Match m) {
    return Int32.Parse(m.Groups[1].Value) * 0.1 + m.Groups[2].Value + "cm"; 
});

Console.WriteLine(ns);
```

And the output is:

```
Half plate ¼ inch length 18.8cm height 106.5cm, ss 316 Lace 3/4 cal 16 x 112 cm ss 304
Air coushion rode 3/16 3.8cm width, 97.2cm length ss316 
Vacuum plate L.97.2cm W.28.8cm ss304
```

Comment: Please leave some relevant comments as well while downvoting.